# Unfair coin toss probability

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 2 methods of getting the probability of heads in an unfair coin toss.

With the 1st method, where the weight of the coin is measured, the probability of getting heads is 75%.

With the 2nd method, where the surface of the coin is examined, the probability of getting heads is 65%.

I want to toss 1000 coins. The problem is that  I can only toss each coin once. There are 2 methods but I can't use both methods for each coin since I can only toss each coin once.

I want the probability of the coin toss to be **HEADS**.

Is there a way I could use the probability of both methods and apply that to only a single toss of each coin?
Or is there any other solution

Comment: I think some more information needs to be specified. If you have a specific unfair coin it must have a certain probability of landing heads, say $ p $. It is not really clear how $ p $ relates to your two methods which give some measures $ p_1 $ and $ p_2 $. One might assume that $ p_1 $ and $ p_2 $ are related to $ p $ and somewhat close, but without knowing more about the relation, we cannot really say any further.

Comment: Are you saying you are tossing 1000 different unfair coins? if so I guess you assume that they don't have the same probability of getting heads, since otherwise it is no different from tossing the same coin 1000 times. And if they have different probabilities tied to them, then I find it unclear what the two methods are providing? I assume method 1 shouldn't provide the answer "75%" for all 1000 different coins, as then it seems the method must be independent of the actual probability and thus tells us nothing at all.

Comment: Similar recent questions with many coins tossed once: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920983/100000-coin-tosses https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922695/statistics-coin-probability